# Programatically adding a row to a DataGridView that is bound to a datasource and already has columns

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I've been trying the whole evening to programatically add rows to my DataGridView but I can't seem to get it working I tried lots of differents ways but none of them seem to be working.

I get no errors, everything looks fine.

I have a WinForm, I added a DataGridView, bound a DataSource to it (table from a SQL 2008 connection).

The data shows up in it, everything is fine but I want to process the data before showing it, so I want to programatically add rows myself.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
    string[] rowArray = new string[]{ "Test", "Test", "Test" };
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(rowArray[0]);
```

-

```
    dataGridView.Rows.Add();
    int newRowIndex = dataGridView.RowCount - 1;
    DataGridViewRow newRow = dataGridView.Rows[newRowIndex];

    newRow.Cells["PurchaseOrderId"].Value = "Test";
    newRow.Cells["SupplierId"].Value = "Test";
    newRow.Cells["State"].Value = "Test";
```

-

```
    DataRow newRow = purchaseOrders.NewRow(); // purchaseOrders = this.purchaseOrderManagerDataSet.PurchaseOrders

    newRow["PurchaseOrderId"] = "Test";
    newRow["SupplierId"] = "Test";
    newRow["State"] = "Test";

    dataGridView.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

None of them adds something to the DataGridView.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the datasource object.

For example if you have a `BindingList`, you can simply add a new object to the list, and it will show in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Okay... I'm kind of lost in all of this, I'm learning all of this at once, so I don't know what is a "BindingList". Do you have any example? Thanks!

Comment: @Tom: Read on MSDN or Google for some blog posts. It is really very handy for databinding lists.

Comment: Oh I read a bit and they seem very useful. I don't have any object called PurchaseOrder yet (name of my table). Is there any way to auto-generate it or I must add a new file and make it myself? Thanks a lot for helping me, very appreciated :)

Comment: AFAIK, you'd have to make it yourself. Just add the data objects, and you might want a constructor.